# Why don't Bash associative arrays maintain index order?

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I'm creating associative arrays to process in a for loop but i'm getting some strange results in index order. Please take a look at this example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A test1=(
    [d]=1w45
    [e]=2dfg
    [m]=3df
    [o]=4df
)

declare -A test2=(
    [d1]=1w45
    [e2]=2dfg
    [m3]=3df
    [o4]=4df
)

declare -A test3=(
    [1d]=1w45
    [2e]=2dfg
    [3m]=3df
    [4o]=4df
)

echo ${!test1[@]}
echo ${!test2[@]}
echo ${!test3[@]}
```

The output will be

```
$ ./test 
d e m o
o4 m3 e2 d1
3m 4o 1d 2e
```

Why is the order of items changing? And how to bypass this behavior? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's how associative arrays work. If you need ordered keys, store the ordered keys in an array.

Comment: The order is dictated by the hash value of the keys; if you don't know the hash function (and you have no need to know that), you can't really predict what that order is.

Comment: What bash version are you using? I can't reproduce `3m 4o 1d 2e`, I get always `1d 3m 2e 4o`.

Comment: This isn't bash-specific at all. Most hash or map types behave this way; it's very recent that Python changed their dict type to have an explicit order, for example, whereas Go intentionally randomizes theirs to avoid denial of service attacks taking advantage of intentionally inefficient bucketing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why don't bash associative arrays maintain index order?

Because they are designed not to do this.

> Why order of items is changing?

Bash [associative array implementation](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/assoc.c#L77) uses a [hash library](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.c) and stores hashes of indexes. These hashes are stored in [buckets](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.c#L39) with 128 [default number of buckets](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.h#L76). The hash is calculated with the function [`hash_string()`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.c#L145) using a simple multiplication and a bitwise XOR. The keys of the associative array are listed [in the order buckets appear](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/assoc.c#L453). [Bucket number is calculated](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.c#L39) by a bitwise AND operation between the hash value of the key and the number of buckets decreased by 1.

I compiled [bash commit 6c6454cb18d7cd30b3b26d5ba6479431e599f3ed](https://github.com/bminor/bash/commit/6c6454cb18d7cd30b3b26d5ba6479431e599f3ed) and for me your script outputs:

```
$ ./test 
o m e d
d1 e2 m3 o4
1d 3m 2e 4o
```

So I copied the `hash_string()` function and written a small C program that would output the bucket number of the keys and compiled and executed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FNV_OFFSET 2166136261
#define FNV_PRIME 16777619

unsigned int
hash_string (s)
     const char *s;
{
  register unsigned int i;

  for (i = FNV_OFFSET; *s; s++)
    {
      i *= FNV_PRIME;
      i ^= *s;
    }

  return i;
}

int main() {
    const char *s[] = {
        "o", "m", "e", "d",
        "d1", "e2", "m3", "o4",
        "1d", "3m", "2e", "4",
    };
    for (int i = 0;  i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s); ++i) {
        printf("%3s %3d\n",
            s[i], 
            hash_string(s[i]) & (128 - 1));
    }
}
```

The program outputs two columns, the key and the bucket number of the key (added extra empty lines):

```
  o 112
  m 114
  e 122
  d 123

 d1  16
 e2  60
 m3  69
 o4 100

 1d  14
 3m  41
 2e  50
 4o  94
```

The order of keys outputted is sorted using the order of buckets in the hash table they are into, so they are outputted in that order. This is why the order of items changed.

That said, you should **not** rely on this behaviour, as the output order of keys can change if the author of bash decides to change the hashing function or make any other change.

> And how to bypass this behavior?

There is no way to bypass this. Bash arrays use hash table to store the hashes. The insertion order of keys is not stored anywhere.

Of course, you can bypass this behaviour by patching `bash` to implement such functionality that you request.

That said, I would just use two arrays:

```
keys=(d1 e2 m3 o4)
elements=(1w45 2dfg 3df 4df)
declare -A test2
for ((i=0;i<${#keys[@]};++i)); do
    test2[${keys[$i]}]="${elements[$i]}"
done
# or maybe something along:
declare -A test2=($(paste -zd <(printf "[%s]=\0" "${keys[@]}") <(printf "%q \0" "${elements[@]}"))
```

That way you can iterate over keys in the order you inserted them in a separate `keys` array.

Answer (score 2):

> Why order of items is changing?

Because generally associative arrays don't *naturally* maintain insertion orders: tree-based ones use natural (sorted) ordering and hashmaps use wherever their hash function lands the keys (which can be randomised per-process or even per-map for security reasons).

The latter also explains why the order of items can even change as you add new items: not only can new items get inserted between existing ones, when the hashmap has to get resized the entire sequence will get "reshuffled" as the entries are rehashed and moved to their new position.

There are languages which either explicitly add ordering as a feature (generally using a doubly linked list), or use a *naturally ordered* hashmap, in which case insertion order is maintained, but you can't assume this property holds unless the language guarantees it. Which bash does not.

Answer (score 0):

According to comments this can be done to bypass this behavior.

```
order=(d1 e2 m3 o4)
declare -A test2=(
    [d1]=1w45
    [e2]=2dfg
    [m3]=3df
    [o4]=4df
)
for key in ${order[@]}; { echo $key ${test2[$key]}; }

d1 1w45
e2 2dfg
m3 3df
o4 4df
```

Or that

```
declare -A test3=(
    [order]="1d 2e 3m 4o"
    [1d]=1w45
    [2e]=2dfg
    [3m]=3df
    [4o]=4df
)
for key in ${test3[order]}; { echo $key ${test3[$key]}; }

1d 1w45
2e 2dfg
3m 3df
4o 4df
```

Is there a better way?

Update, according to accepted answer associative array isn't the right choice if you need a strict order in for loop, better use something like this:

```
key=(d1   e2   m3  o4 ) 
val=(1w45 2dfg 3df 4df)

for i in ${!key[@]}; {
    echo ${key[$i]} ${val[$i]}
}
```

Or this

```
key_val=(
    "d1 1w45"
    "e2 2dfg"
    "m3 3df"
    "o4 4df")  

for item in "${key_val[@]}"; {
    sub=($item)
    echo ${sub[0]} ${sub[1]}
}
```

Or that

```
keys=(d1      e2      m3     o4    )
      d1=1w45 e2=2dfg m3=3df o4=4df

for key in ${keys[@]}; {
    echo $key ${!key}
}
```

Comment: There is not a better way. Other languages have hash-type data structures that maintain insertion order, but not bash.

Answer (score 0):

Can be explained shortly as:

- Integer indexed arrays have an implicit automatically incremented index and allow an explicitly assigned index that creates sparse arrays.
  If you add a record with an explicit index to an indexed array; the index may no longer reflect the insertion order

Whereas:

- Associative arrays only have an explicit string index.

To sum it up:

An implicit incremental index reflects the insertion order; whereas an explicit imperative index does not.