# Associative array default key sort bash

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I have following bash-script with associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A sites

sites[75]=valueCheck
sites[76]=valueCheck
sites[77]=valueCheck
sites[78]=valueCheck
sites[79]=valueCheck
sites[80]=valueCheck

echo "${!sites[@]}"
```

When i run it, i recognized that the keys are not in the given order:

```
/test.sh
78 79 75 76 77 80
```

Why it pushes 78 & 79 in front of 75?

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396504/why-dont-bash-associative-arrays-maintain-index-order)

Comment: Don't be sorry you asked a question which already had an answer elsewhere. Duplicates are useful. Duplicates are a way of asking the same question in different ways. This makes it easier for other users to find what they look for. If you did not find the duplicate, it implies that the original question does not have enough alternative ways of asking it ;-)