# Bash: Copy an associative array to a normal array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm currently learning script programming, and I'm trying to copy an associative array to a normal array. Here's what I got so far:

```
declare -A array
array[0]=0
array[1]=4
array[2]=4
array[3]=3

copy=${array[@]} 

echo ${copy[0]}
echo ${copy[1]}
echo ${copy[2]}
echo ${copy[3]}

echo ${array[0]}
echo ${array[1]}
echo ${array[2]}
echo ${array[3]}
```

this method stores all the value into copy[0], which means keys are not copied. Any comments will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The associative array seems to have numeric indexes -- is that intentional? Do you want to preserve the indexes when copying it to a normal array?

Answer (score 0):

Copy is not an array but var, to make an array use this:

```
copy=( "${array[@]}" )
```

But remember that associative array do not preserve order, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396504/why-dont-bash-associative-arrays-maintain-index-order)